# How to open an external image viewer to view a drawable instance in android?

Tags: android, imageview, viewer

I have an `ImageView` that displays a picture in android. Essentially, I want to be able to open the picture in full screen with zooming capabilities when the `ImageView` is tapped.
Probably by using an external viewer to which I pass the drawable instance.

Other relevant information:

- Context: The image view is actually a [ParseImageView](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseImageView.html) (an extension of ImageView) which has been populated using a [ParseFile](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseFile.html) (image file loaded from parse.com) asyncronously.
- minSDK: 14
- IDE: Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the [ImageViewTouch](https://github.com/sephiroth74/ImageViewZoom) Library for zoom features with a single line of code,

```
setImageBitmap( final Bitmap bitmap, Matrix matrix, float minZoom, float maxZoom );
```